# Strange Python/Numpy behavior when a function modifies and returns the input variable

Tags: python, numpy

I have a test script here where the input and output to a function are the same variable. The example code is as follows

```
import numpy as np


def sign(x: np.ndarray):
    # Return x/abs(x)
    nz_idx = np.abs(x) != 0
    x[nz_idx] = x[nz_idx] / np.abs(x[nz_idx])
    return x


if __name__ ==  "__main__":
    x = np.zeros((10,1), dtype=float)
    x[:, 0] = np.arange(1,11)    
    print(x)
    y = sign(x)
    print(x)
```

I would have expected the output to be

> [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]

> [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]

since the function should not modify the variable `x` that is input to it.

But what I get is

> [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]

> [0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]

which I clearly know is wrong

One way to fix this is to add another variable to the function `sign`

```
def sign(x: np.ndarray):
    z = x.copy()
    nz_idx = np.abs(z) != 0
    z[nz_idx] = z[nz_idx] / np.abs(z[nz_idx])
    return z
```

which then gives me the correct output. Is this expected behaviour in Python/Numpy or is this a bug?

Comment: Python isn't pass-by-value - passing objects to functions, or returning objects from functions, does not implicitly make copies. Your changed code works not because of the extra variable, but because of the explicit copy in `z = x.copy()`.

Comment: So, how does one avoid such bugs? I mean, what would be good programming practice here since some operations on numpy arrays (and some other data types) modify the original array without forcing a copy?

Comment: This isn't just an issue when writing functions.  You always have to be aware of when an action modifies an object as opposed to producing a new one.

Comment: Numpy creates a lot of new temporary arrays (for example `x[nz_idx]` and `np.abs` create 4 arrays, not to mention `/` and even `!=`). In-place operation are not usual with it. The standard way to do things with Numpy is this not to modify the input but create new array (this not very efficient but if you want high performance, then Numpy might not be the best tool as well as Python actually). If you want to do that for sake of performance, you need to *document this* clearly (see [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)).